# Copy gdata jars to root dir: `WEB-INF/lib` or to subdirs: `WEB-INF/lib/gdata/blogger/2.0`, etc?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, jar

I'm using **Google's** `gdata` library. I installed it in my *local Maven repository* because it is not available from **Maven Central** using a `pom`.

I want to move it to my `WEB-INF/lib` directory so that I do not have to wait for the dozens of "*Downloading*" messages from **Maven** each time I restart the server.

However, they are currently in a directory structure like this:

```
~\wiki\.m2\repository\gdata\base\1.0
~\wiki\.m2\repository\gdata\blogger\2.0
~\wiki\.m2\repository\gdata\books\1.0
```

If I want to install the jars in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder so that the pom is not needed, can I copy the entire gdata directory to

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

Or should I just copy each jar file one-by-one into the base of the `WEB-INF/lib` directory rather than:

```
WEB-INF/lib/gdata/base/1.0
WEB-INF/lib/gdata/blogger/2.0
WEB-INF/lib/gdata/books/1.0
```

Comment: Why is this tagged eclipse and spring?

Comment: This question is obsoleted by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025629/solution-for-a-jar-file-not-findable-in-the-web-inf-lib-folder-nor-src-main-re

Answer (score 2):

If you create extra folders inside `/WEB-INF/lib`, they are by default not taken in the servletcontainer's runtime classpath. So, either just don't create those folders (put whole JAR straight in `lib`), or explicitly add the paths to those new folders to servletcontainer's runtime classpath.